# Cannot access device / WD Portable Game Drive 5.0 TB USB

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, disk-management

I've tried two cables and using two different computers to access my WD Portable 5.0 TB portable game drive that has a USB interface. Dmesg seems ok with line

`[ 4586.948425] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through`

However when I try to access the device via smartctl / cfdisk / etc to get more information, then dmesg is populated with errors.

Does anyone have experience with these scenarios?

Should I look for help on a linux mailing list?

```
[ 4531.648581] .......................................................ready
[ 4586.945308] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[ 4586.946119] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 9767475200 512-byte logical blocks: (5.00 TB/4.55 TiB)
[ 4586.946123] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[ 4586.947284] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 4586.947288] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
[ 4586.948419] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 4586.948425] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 4622.130073] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x3-0x1
[ 4622.368355] usb 4-2: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[ 4622.379174] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x3-0x1
[ 4627.488329] usb 4-2: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[ 4632.864288] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 4638.244207] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 4638.452112] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 12, error -62
[ 4643.872208] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 4649.248179] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 4649.456152] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 12, error -62
[ 4654.880182] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 4660.260151] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 4660.468115] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 12, error -62
[ 4665.888149] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 4671.264076] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 4671.472070] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 12, error -62
[ 4671.488227] usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 12
[ 4671.504071] print_req_error: 2 callbacks suppressed
[ 4671.504087] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 4671.504095] buffer_io_error: 2 callbacks suppressed
[ 4671.504096] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 4671.504164] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 4671.504169] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 4671.504190] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 4671.504192] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 4671.504206] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 4671.504208] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 4671.504213] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[ 4671.504221] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 4671.504222] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 4671.504235] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 4671.504236] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 4671.504247] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 4671.504248] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 4671.504259] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 4671.504261] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 4671.504266] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[ 4671.504274] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 4671.504275] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 4671.504286] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 4671.504288] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 4671.504321]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[ 4671.532205] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 4671.532212] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[ 4671.532219] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 4671.532221] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[ 4671.532225] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[ 4671.532226] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[ 4671.532236] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[ 4676.896090] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 4682.272070] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 4682.480039] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 13, error -62
[ 4687.904053] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 4693.280033] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 4693.488002] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 14, error -62
[ 4693.496092] usb usb4-port2: attempt power cycle
[ 4699.680018] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 4705.056003] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 4705.263969] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 15, error -62
[ 4710.687982] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 4716.063965] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 4716.271934] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 16, error -62
[ 4716.279918] usb usb4-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Comment: is one of the cables you tried the original cable the device came with? what smartctl / cfdisk /etc command options are you issuing?

Comment: This feels like a hardware issue. Either the cable, or insufficient power to the drive, or the drive itself is damaged, or the controller is faulty. Notice that not all USB drive controllers allow access to SMART at all.

Comment: If you're looking to recover data from the drive I recommend posting in https://www.reddit.com/r/datarecovery/